# React: cannot acces component props when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack

When I reload the 'details' page (which is not the homepage) on my app I get the error:

**"TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'flag' of 'country' as it is undefined."**

I guess that as the data is passed from the homepage to the other if we don't go from the homepage to the details page we can't load the data from the API.

After some researchs I concluded that I had to modify some things in the webpack.config.js but as I created my app with the command:

**npx create-react-app my-app**

it is hard for me to find the webpack config file and I'm not even sure that this would be the solution.

A card on the homepage (when clicked, leads to a detail page for the specific country):

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Card = ({country}) => {
    const {flag, name, population, subregion, capital} = country;

    const new_population = population.toLocaleString();

    const newTo = {
        pathname: `/details/${name}`,
        country: country
    };

    return <Link to={newTo} className='card'>

        <img src={flag} alt={name}></img>
        <div className='subCard'>
            <h2>{name}</h2>
            <p>Population: {new_population}</p>
            <p>Region: {subregion}</p>
            <p>Capital: {capital}</p>
        </div>

    </Link>;
}

export default Card;
```

The page you are brought to when clicking on a Card:

```
import { useLocation, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Details = () => {
    const { country } = useLocation();
    
    const { 
        flag, 
        name, 
        nativeName, 
        population, 
        region, 
        subregion, 
        capital, 
        topLevelDomain, 
        currencies, 
        languages, 
        borders } = country; 
        //arrays: currencies, languages, borders, topLevelDomain

    return <div className='details'>
        <Link to={`/`} >Back</Link>
        <img src={flag} alt={name}></img>
        
            //etc
    </div>;
export default Details;
}
```

My Homepage:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useFetch } from './useFetch'
import Card from './Card';
import Searchbar from './Searchbar';

const Home = () => {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');
    

    const { isLoading, countries, isError } = useFetch(url); //custom hook

    if(!isLoading && !isError){
        return <div className='home'>
        <Searchbar setUrl={setUrl}>
            <DropdownMenu setRegion={setRegion}></DropdownMenu>
            
        </Searchbar>
        <div className='cards'>
          {countries.map((country, index)=>{
              return <Card key={index} id={index} country={country} ></Card> 
          })} 
        </div>
    </div>;
//etc
```

My App.js (don't know if it's necessary):

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Navbar from './Navbar';
//page(s)
import Home from './Home'
import Error from './Error'
import Details from './Details'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/'>
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/details/:id' children={<Details/>}></Route>
      <Route path='*'>
        <Error></Error>
      </Route>  
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Could you please tell me if modifying the webpack config file would be the best solution or not? If not what could I do?

Btw if you need code that I didn't show here I'm very sorry and just tell me I'll modify my post.

Comment: I am not sure about the webpack solution you are proposing, but what I would do is `return null` while your component props are still loading. So for example, in your `Card` component write before you destructure `country`, do a check if `country` is falsy and return `null` if that is the case. Basically: `if (!country) return null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass data using a `<Link>` component, you need to add it to the `state` variable.

In your card component, your `newTo` variable should be:

```
const newTo = { 
   pathname: `/details/${name}`,
   state: {country: country}
}
```

[React Router - Link component](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)

And then to access the `country` variable on the Details page, use

```
const {state} = useLocation()

const country = state.country
```

Comment: In addition to this, you should check if the `country` object is present in `location.state` on the Details page. If not (this can happen when you refresh the page or you visit the link on a separate tab), then you should fetch the data on the details page and then render it once loaded.

Comment: Using the correct syntax (from your first comment) is enough to avoid getting an error when refreshing, but I'll either rafactor a bit or fetch in Details as you said to be able to access a details page in a new tab, Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's particularly useful when sharing the link. If someone opens that link on their browser, they would not have access to the shared state in the location prop.

Answer (score 1):

preserving the state in the `Link` is not recommended approach IMHO . Because the only way you have the state will be to click on the card component . But the problem here is once you click on the card gone to the respective page and if you hit refresh . Your state under `location` will be `undefined` because refreshing the page causes your App to re-render .

so if you want to preserve state across routes then i would recommend you to use the

`React Context` or Other state management libraries like `redux` or `mobx`

Comment: I feel like using useContext would be better aswell, I might refactor a bit, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not the Webpack config.

The issue is that you are not passing country in correctly. In your details function, console.log(countries) and see what is being passed in.